# Is there a way to get trackpad force events in JavaScript in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In Safari it's possible to get the pressure someone exerts on the trackpad of a Macbook (see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/RespondingtoForceTouchEventsfromJavaScript.html)). So let's suppose you have a generic trackpad that also supports a form of pressure sensitivity, is there an event listener (or something else) that will give you the pressure sensitivity value?

I've been searching on Google and I can't seem to find it. It probably doesn't exist? I'm asking here just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Force Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Force_Touch_events) is

> Not part of any specification

You can simulate it with time of touch event like plugin [Pressure.js](https://pressurejs.com/) do